# How can a global class change a Text View inside an object?

Tags: android

I have a GlobalClass class that is global.

So inside this class I have an object of another class that contains the layout

```
public class GlobalClass extends Application{
    private ClassThatHasTextView foo= null;

    function(){
        foo.text.setText("jdajiodsa");
    }
}


public class ClassThatHasTextView extends Activity{

    TextView text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ClassThatHasTextView);
    }
}
```

What I want to do is to change the `text` (that is inside the ClassThatHasTextView) in a function that is inside the `GlobalClass`, is it possible?

How can I change the text?

I am thinking about some sollutions like

```
1) this.foo.text.setText("dsajiojdsa")
2)this.getApplicationContext().foo.text.setText("idasisda")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think this is even correct to do as you should avoid using application for globals (try using a singleton class) and as far as I know you should never have an activity inside application as application isn't something visual.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Setter and Getters

In your GlobalClass

```
    private TextView textView;

    public void setText(String text) {
         if (this.textView != null)
              this.textView.setText(text)
    }

    public void setTextView(TextView textView){
         this.textView = textView;
    }
```

In your Activity class

```
     GlobalClass globalClass = (GlobalClass) getApplicationContext();
     globalClass.setText("dsajiojdsa");
```

Make sure that you set the TextView at your Application class first.